# Symbolically solving equation for a given variable in Maxima

Tags: equation, maxima, equation-solving, parametric-equations, wxmaxima

I can solve an equation using Maxima by using the commands below.

```
kill(all);
A:A; phase:phase; solve(A*cos(2*pi*f*t+phase)=y,phase);
```

And it gives me the correct answer.

```
phase=acos(y/A)-2*f*pi*t
```

[image]

But when I try and solve for just the top portion of an equation the `x(n+1)` portion. Here's the equation.

[image]

See website [Clifford Attractor](https://fronkonstin.com/2017/11/07/drawing-10-million-points-with-ggplot-clifford-attractors/).

It's not what I expected. The equation I use is below:

```
kill(all);
x:x; a:a; c:c; n:n; solve(sin(a*y(n))+c*cos(a*x(n))=x*(n+1),x);
```

What I get is :

```
x=(sin(a*y(n))+c*cos(a*x(n)))/(n+1)
```

[image]

I expected it to be something like:

```
x[n] = sin(a*y[n-1])+c*cos(a*x[n-1]);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using wxMaxima 18.02.0 in ubuntu 18.04 64bit